# Learning Java public static main method

Tags: java

I am learning java and I have come across the following problem: write the code for a single file that implements a public static void main(String[]) method when called with any array of strings, can anyone explain how I do this, it to used with an immutable abstract data type of a list of string?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sort of just blanking in general

Answer (score 4):

The args[] array contains a list of command line parameters given to your program. So:

```
java SomeClass runInBackground debugModeOn
```

would result in the args array:

```
["runInBackground", "debugModeOn"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class FirstMain {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
    }
}
```